# strange C# memory leak using GDI

Tags: c#, wpf

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            new Action(() =>
            {
                if (currentImage != null)
                {
                    currentImage.Dispose();
                    currentImage = null;
                }
                this.currentImage = render.render(value);
                this.mainImage.Source =
                    System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                        currentImage.GetHbitmap(),
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        Int32Rect.Empty,
                        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            }));
```

Note this.mainImage is a Image controller in WPF.
I found there are some memory leak when I execute the sentence "this.mainImage.Source = XXXX"
I found there is no way to release the memory held by this.mainImage.Source

Comment: Might be worth rephrasing this as a question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to call DeleteObject on that hbitmap you are retrieving from currentImage.GetHbitmap(). [Here's the MSDN link for GetHbitmap.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no straight forward way to release a resource allocated by `Image.Source`, not that I'm aware of. But there are different ways to avoid it, *as much as possible*.

One of possible solutions, when you know that you *will not manipulate that element*, is make it [Freezable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx). In this case WPF framework avoid tracing an events on that object, as you declared it "readonly". So you notably imrove a performace of your application.

Old one, but still good article:

[Finding Memory Leaks in WPF-based applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx)